# Animal Crossing New Horizons: How to move out most recent villager?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

My wife has 8 villagers; 7 of which she wants to keep on her island in ACNH, but the most recent is one she'd like to get rid of (and then go on Nook Mile Island Tours to find a new one).  We've been time travelling a day at a time for about 2 months and this villager has never once had a thought bubble but we've seen all the other villagers with the bubble.  We're seeing conflicting information online on whether this is because it's the most recent villager.

Can anyone confirm whether the most recent villager will eventually ask to leave, or whether we're stuck constantly replacing them via Amiibo cards or natural campsite visitors?
Current version of ACNH is 1.11.1 in case patches in different versions made a difference.

Edit:
Although I've marked this as a duplicate, it's worth noting that having spent a LONG time testing that I confirm that it seems that your most recent villager will NEVER ask to leave.